# View details of table row through ID

Tags: php

I have a table that displays a concert tour name, year and a view info link that is supposed to take the user to information about the specific tour using it's ID. Here's a snippet from it:

```html
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['Tour_Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Year'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<a href=all_shows.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>View info</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

I believe this works since the correct ID comes up in the URL when directed to the new page, but it comes out blank. I can't seem to get the information in my show_info table to appear. I've tried so many different things and I've hit a brick wall at this point. Extremely new to all of this so any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Details</title>
<body>
<?

@ $db = mysql_pconnect("localhost","medinasa","");

if (!$db)
{
 echo "ERROR: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
 exit;
}
mysql_select_db("medinasa_shows");
$id = $_GET['ID'];
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM show_info WHERE ID = '$id'";
$query = mysql_query($query_string);
?>
<h3 class="box-title">User Details</h3>
<?    
              while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                  echo "<h1>".$row['Tour_Name']. "</h1>";
                  echo "<h1>".$row['City']. "</h1>";
                  echo "<h1>".$row['Year']. "</h1>";
                  echo "<h1>".$row['Headliner']. "</h1>";
                  echo "<h1>".$row['Opener']. "</h1>";
                  echo "<h1>".$row['Comments']. "</h1>";
              }    
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Also, the problem is that (by default) PHP parameters are case sensitive. Instead of `$_GET['ID']` you're looking for `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: where's your table tag? `<table></table>`

Comment: Also you haven't terminated your `<head>` tag

Comment: @ObsidianAge Ah, I will definitely update it to MySQLi. Thank you for the heads up! It's now giving me an error "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..." not too sure what this means?

Comment: I've found that most people here asked a question about fetching SQL query they always expect there MUST RETURN SOMETHING! They don't used to test if it returns anything by `var_dump` or `print_r`, or even the simplest method is to simplify the SQL as simple as possible, just make it as `SELECT * FROM TABLE` without any criteria.

Comment: That error means your query failed and `$query` is false.

Answer (score 0):

mysql is depreccated you should use mysqli or pdo.

see below code with mysqli

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Details</title>
<body>
<?

// my_user is your sql username
// my_password is your mysql password
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","medinasa_shows");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "ERROR: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
    exit;
}

$id = $_GET['ID'];

$query_string="SELECT * FROM show_info WHERE ID = '$id'";
$query=mysqli_query($db,$query_string);

?>
<h3 class="box-title">User Details</h3>
<?    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<h1>".$row['Tour_Name']. "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>".$row['City']. "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>".$row['Year']. "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>".$row['Headliner']. "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>".$row['Opener']. "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>".$row['Comments']. "</h1>";
    }    
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```